# How to wait for mdadm RAID array's resync process to fully complete?

Tags: linux, rust, raid, mdadm

I currently have a logic to wait for the resync process to finish by looking at `/sys/block/mdXXX/md/raid_state` to be `clean` and assume that the resync has finished. However, I don't think this is correct as the raid can be in clean state while the resync is still happening.

What is a guaranteed way to ensure that newly created raid1 array using mdadm has fully completed the resync process?

Does mdadm have an inbuilt way of specifying whether we want to wait for resync to finish or not?

I have a Rust program that is orchestrating RAID creation using mdadm.

```
    // above create RAID-1 using mdadm --create
    loop {
        // seems like the file below is always having "clean" even when resync is happening
        let raid_state = read_file("/sys/block/mdXXX/md/raid_state")
        let sync_complete = raid_state == "clean";

        if sync_complete {
            // do more
        }
    }
```

Comment: Independent of wether `raid_state` is the correct variable to wait on it's probably better to use a crate like `inotify` to let the OS wake your program once something changes than busy loop reading that file.

Comment: Does inotify work with `/sys` files? Thought the where like proc, generated on read so not inotifyable. I welcome being wrong however.

Comment: Uh  right, I briefly looked into the inotify manpage, found nothing and assumed it'd work. [This Q/A](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/398204/inotifywait-not-alterting-when-device-created) suggests it works for parts of `/sys` / `/proc` though it's really unclear which parts. Still there has to be a better way than to spin poll on a file in there, maybe a `udev` rule of sorts.

Comment: Spin poll with sleep is theoretically less ideal than something using inotify/udev, this is true, but it's also dead-simple logic that is guaranteed to work, where arranging a callback can fail for any number of reasons that the program may never actually be informed about. I would particularly worry about new kernel/udev versions that break the callback mechanism, while polling is only going to break if the layout of `/sys` changes.

Comment: [The Linux RAID docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/md.html) mention that the `array_state` file can be `select`/`poll`ed for changes. Not sure if that's related to your `raid_state` file.

Comment: Why do you want to wait? You can use md RAID while it's rebuilding.

Comment: I agree. But requirement is to ensure that resync/rebuild has finished before mounting and starting to use the RAID array.

Comment: Check https://linux.die.net/man/8/mdadm, option -F